# Angular 7: Dar biding em um objeto que vai receber um json de um HTTP GET

Tags: angular, typescript

Digamos que eu tenha o objeto tipado:

```
x: Endereco

public interface Endereco {
  rua: string;
  numero: number;
}
```

E tenho um http GET que alimentará essa variável x. O problema é que no request eu recebo um json com o parâmetro "bairro" que eu não quero que vá para a minha variável x. Como eu faço pra 'filtrar' isso?

```
{
  rua: "nome da rua",
  numero: 34,
  bairro: "Não quero isso"
}
```

Atualmente, faço dessa maneira:

```
http.get<Endereco>('url')
   .subscribe(resposta => this.x = resposta)
```

Aqui a variável X se transforma em um objeto com o parâmetro bairro, e eu não quero que aconteça isso.

Comment: `http.get<Endereco>('url')
   .subscribe(resposta => { this.x.rua  = resposta['rua'] this.x.numero = resposta['rua'] })`tenta assim

Comment: O problema de ir setando manualmente é que eu posso ter um objeto com 20 parâmetros ou mais. Terei que setar todos manualmente? Não entendo como o typescript possa forçar a um objeto tipado um parâmetro que não se encontra nele.

Comment: João, você não precisa ter todas as propriedades do seu objecto igual aos que vem da resposta. a unica coisa que vai acontecer é que se objeto irá estender.

Comment: Mas eu não quero que ele se estenda, quero só as propriedades que defini nele. Acho que deveria ter um método de se fazer isso sem eu ter que setar as propriedades uma por uma. Trabalho com um banco gigantesco, então isso acaba se tornando um incômodo, mas valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que mapear o seu modelo da resposta da api pro seu modelo de estado interno da aplicação, para isso o melhor é usar o operador map:

```
http.get<Endereco>('url')
    .pipe(
         map(resposta=>{
            return {
               resposta.rua,
               resposta.numero
            }
        })
     )
   .subscribe(resposta => this.x = resposta)
```